# How to detect exception in database

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, drools, rule-engine

We want to implement an exception engine. It needs to detects abnormal data in database. There are a few attributes we picked out as the indicator of an exception. If value of one or combination of a couple of these attributes exceeds some threshold, it is considered as exception. An notification of the exception should be sent to the admin.

I wonder if there is a way to constantly monitor these columns from the tables and catch the exception in real time. My database is Postgres. Would Drools rule engine help in this case?

Comment: How about [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html)?

Comment: How about validating data prior to putting it in the database?

Comment: @NathanHughes It is not about whether data is valid. One use case would be if a ticket is open for more than 150 days, it is an exception.

Comment: @Andreas Looks like trigger works mostly on table level or row level. What if an exception is defined based on attribute A from table 1 and B from table 2. Some algorithm applies to the two values and the result determines whether or not it is an exception

Comment: @ddd There is nothing preventing a trigger from querying other tables.

Comment: @Andreas triggers are fired by operation events including INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE. This will sure capture some of exceptions. But there are a number of exceptions have nothing to do with these events. For example, a ticket was open 179 days ago. It is not an exception until tomorrow because it hits 180 day threshold we defined. Another exception would be, the ticket is still open when there are more than 5 technician services.

Comment: @ddd Guess you should have clarified your question more, so we wouldn't waste time suggesting things that don't help.

Answer (score 0):

A rules engine would be very well equipped to detect any combination of data according to the defined rules. You need to keep all data in the working memory of the rules engine, and to repeat all insertions, deletions and modifications.

To detect data of a certain age, add a fact representing the current Date. (I don't think that your simple use case "older than N days" warrants event processing where subtler relations between data items can be expressed.)